# Error request power-well from i915 ( Lenovo L440 - Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, brightness

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 14.04 on my Lenovo L440 and until yesterday I hadn't experienced any problems, when I started my laptop and received the error message:

> [ 3.331621] hda-intel Error request power-well from i915.

After the boot, I couldn't change the brightness of my laptop screen using my keyboard anymore and the system seemed to perform very laggy.

What does this mean and how can I fix it?